# Redirect page URL to specific IP address

Tags: redirect, dns, a-records

Say I have two servers, each with its own website, that share a domain name (www.sitename.com). As far as I know, you can only point the domain name to one of the servers.

Is it possible to point individual page url's (www.sitename.com/page) to either server through htaccess, DNS records, or otherwise?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this via **.htaccess** file, in which i redirected my website to IP address and then to sub-domain, use can make use of the same.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hardworkerz\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.hardworkerz\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/103\.7\.129\.132\/CorporateUI" [R=301,L]
```

In this redirection code i have redirected my website hardworkerz.net and www.hardworkerz.net to IP address **103.7.129.132** and further to subdomain **CorporateUI** permanently.

Comment: Thanks man. We ended up doing something different but this appears to be what I was trying to do. Much appreciated - will use it in the future I'm sure.

Comment: Mate you can upvote and tick up the answer if these helped you out.